# is it possible to get a range of results surrounding the specifically matched one?

Tags: mysql

I realize that I can do this in code, but I was curious if there's a straight SQL way to select (for instance) 10 results in addition to the one that your query matches...

so, let's say I had a database of players all of whom had scores and I wanted to show a user the 5 players whose scores are behind theirs and the 5 ahead... so, I select their row but now should I just use an or in the where clause and say something like...

```
select score as selectedScore from player_scores where playerId = xxxx
or (score > selectedScore - 5 and score < selectedScore + 5)
```

I realize that this implies all the scores are in exact order, and I'd modify the query to pull the userIds from those scores, so this is just a pseudo example for the sake of the question.

I suspect that would work, but is that the *right way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) to combine two queries that use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to select the next 5 and the previous 5 respectively; by using a self-join in each query, one can find all other players adjacent to the desired player's score (this assumes that `playerId` is unique in `player_scores` however):

```
(
  SELECT   p1.playerId, p1.score
  FROM     player_scores AS p1 JOIN player_scores AS p2 ON p1.score >= p2.score
  WHERE    p2.playerId = ?
  ORDER BY p1.score ASC
  LIMIT    6
) UNION ALL (
  SELECT   p1.playerId, p1.score
  FROM     player_scores AS p1 JOIN player_scores AS p2 ON p1.score <  p2.score
  WHERE    p2.playerId = ?
  ORDER BY p1.score ASC
  LIMIT    5
)
```

Comment: ooh... that's very nice. I think you have to remove the AND however, because otherwise it will require that the playerId = xxxxx and that would only apply to THAT player and not to the 5 behind and ahead, right?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: My misunderstanding; see my revised answer above.  Although, to be honest, you could directly make the two queries separately from your application.